# Calculate $\rho_s$ at interface between two cylinders, knowing $\rho_v(r)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider a system of two hollow cylinders of height $h$, $r_1$ outer and $r_2$ inner radii of cylinder 1 and  $r_2$ and $r_3$ those of cylinder 2.

Considering variations only with the radius, I have a (discrete) volume charge distribution $\rho_v$(*r*) where *r* is between $r_1$ and $r_3$. I am trying to find the surface charge $\rho_s$(*r$_2$*) (or rather/at least, on a small fraction of space around the $r_2$ mark) and I am stumped.

Is there a way I can get $\rho_s$(*r$_2$*) knowing $\rho_v$(*r*) ?

I considered that [ $r_a$ = $r_2$ - $\delta$ ] and  [ $r_b$ = $r_2$ + $\delta$ ]

I said that the charge, $$Q = \int_{V} \rho_v dV = \int_{S} \rho_s dS$$

Now, I am unsure how to proceed (or if this is the way).

1) 
 I considered $dV = Area(r) dr $ and $Area(r) = 2\pi h r $ (side area of a cylinder), so the first integral: $$Q = 2\pi h \int_{r_a}^{r_b} r\rho_v(r) dr$$
and by considering a constant height *h* (horisontal plan), $dS = r dr d\theta = 2\pi r dr$, the second integral:
$$ Q = 2\pi \int_{}^{} r \rho_s dr $$
By equaling the two above expressions, $$ h \int_{r_a}^{r_b} r\rho_v(r) dr = \int_{}^{} r\rho_s dr$$  Can I compute (at least using DISCRETE VALUES) $\rho_s$ as follows? $$(\frac{d}{dr} h \int_{r_a}^{r_b} r\rho_v(r) dr )/r$$

2) Same beginning as 1) only that the Volume of a hollow cylinder should be $\pi h (r_b^2-r_a^2)$ and the Lateral surface of a hollow cylinder is $2\pi h (r_a+r_b)$ . This translates into:
$$Q = \rho_v V = \rho_s S $$
so $$\rho_s = \rho_v V/S = \rho_v (r_b-r_a)/2 = \rho_v \delta $$ So $$\rho_s(r_2) = \rho_v(r_2) \delta $$
(But this is most certainly FALSE ?).

3) 
I consider $dV = r dr d\theta dz$ and $dS = r dr d\theta$

So $$ Q = \int_{r_a}^{r_b} r\rho_v(r) dr \int_{\theta}^{} d\theta \int_{h}^{} dz = \int_{r_a}^{r_b} r\rho_s dr \int_{\theta}^{} d\theta $$
If I simplify the integral in $\theta$ from each side of the equation and take integral of $dz$ to be $h$, I end up with same expression as 1), although I am not sure about the limits for $\rho_s$ in this configuration.

What I am calculating is mathematically sound, or I made wrong assumptions when trying to calculate $\rho_s$ at the interface between the two cylinders from knowing $\rho_v(r)$ values along the "*r*" axis ? None of the above outcomes seem to be correct. Please advise.

EDIT: What appears to be correct is $$ \rho_s(r_2) = (1/r_{2|left})\int_{r_1}^{r_{2|left}} r\rho_v(r) dr - (1/r_{2|right})\int_{r_1}^{r_{2|right}} r\rho_v(r) dr  $$

But I do not understand how or why.

EDIT 2: With above notations, it's:
$$ \rho_s(r_2) = (1/r_a)\int_{r_1}^{r_a} r\rho_v(r) dr - (1/r_b)\int_{r_1}^{r_b} r\rho_v(r) dr  $$
and if I consider some hypotheses like $(1/r_a)$ and $(1/r_b)$ to be approximate equal to $(1/r_2)$, it transforms into:
$$ \rho_s(r_2) = (1/r_2)(-\int_{r_a}^{r_b} r\rho_v(r) dr )  $$
and this appears like $$ \int_{r_a}^{r_b} \rho_s dr = -\int_{r_a}^{r_b} r\rho_v dr $$
and by solving the integral I get $$ \rho_s (r_b - r_a) = -\rho_v (r_b^2-r_a^2)/2 => \rho_s = - \rho_v (r_b-r_a)/2 => \rho_s(r_2) = - \rho_v(r_2) \delta $$
 Which roughly feels similar (with an extra 'minus' sign) to STATEMENT 2) which I considered to be false.

EDIT 3:
I considered for dV 
$$dV = r dr d\theta dz $$
and for dS a vertical cylinder of constant radius $r$
$$dS = r d\theta dz $$
as $Q = \int_{V}^{} \rho_v dV = \int_{S}^{} \rho_s dS$, 
$$ \int_{V}^{} \rho_v dV = \int_{r_a}^{r_b} \rho_v r dr \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{0}^{h} dz = 2\pi h \int_{r_a}^{r_b} \rho_v r dr$$
$$ \int_{S}^{} \rho_s dS = \rho_s r_2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{0}^{h} dz = 2\pi h r_2 \rho_s$$
So $ 2\pi h r_2 \rho_s = 2\pi h \int_{r_a}^{r_b} \rho_v r dr $ , and then $$\rho_s = (\int_{r_a}^{r_b} \rho_v r dr )/ r_2 $$

This seems valid if I consider $\rho_s$ over the cylinder surface at point $r_2$ and $\rho_v$ over the cylinder volume between the points $r_a$ and $r_b$.  But the only drawback I see that it really depends on the value of $r_b$-$r_a$. If its $1\mu m$ or $7\mu m$ I get results varying with 2-3 orders of magnitude. But I suppose that's the only drawback as $\rho_s$ is accumulating on a mathematical surface and $\rho_v$ varies over $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post as answer my Edit 3 above.

Considering for $dV$
$$dV = r dr d\theta dz $$
and for $dS$ a vertical cylinder of constant radius $r$
$$dS = r d\theta dz $$
as $Q = \int_{V}^{} \rho_v dV = \int_{S}^{} \rho_s dS$, 
$$ \int_{V}^{} \rho_v dV = \int_{r_a}^{r_b} \rho_v r dr \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{0}^{h} dz = 2\pi h \int_{r_a}^{r_b} \rho_v r dr$$
$$ \int_{S}^{} \rho_s dS = \rho_s r_2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{0}^{h} dz = 2\pi h r_2 \rho_s$$
So $ 2\pi h r_2 \rho_s = 2\pi h \int_{r_a}^{r_b} \rho_v r dr $ , and then $$\rho_s(r_2) = (\int_{r_a}^{r_b} \rho_v r dr )/ r_2 $$